# diffrence between set default java version and used java version

Tags: java, ubuntu

In my machine installed two java version and when I run  "update-alternatives --config java" commands show

### Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status

0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto 
mode

1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode

*2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1069      manual mode

default java version is java 8.

But when run java-version commands show java version "1.7.0_131"

I export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/ but don't fix this problem.

I don't know what is happen?

Comment: Did you restart the terminal?

Comment: yes, I think about it but doesn't fix

Answer (score 0):

`export PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin":$PATH
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/"`

Those two way are different. You should add the path at the head.